# Is it possible to partially apply a React component?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming

Say I have a `<Button>` component which takes two properties: `text` and `id` e.g.,

```
<Button text="delete" id="123"/>
```

Now say I have a list of user ids: `[101, 102, 103, …]`

Would it be possible to partially apply `<Button>`? e.g.,

```
ids.map(<Button text="delete" id={__}>)
```

Where `__` is just a placeholder waiting to be replaced with the current id.

If it was possible, would partially applying a React component have any adverse effect on the [React Reconciliation Algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you do not know the way to use .map function in react well.      
.map((_box, _i) => { return (<></>) })      Will I send you a full code here? Or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 5):

You could use two ways

one, which is not really a partial

```
ids.map((id)=><Button text="delete" id={id} />)
```

and the partial one which is really extracting the function above and using it

```
const PartialDeleteButton = (id) => <Button text="delete" id={id} />

ids.map(PartialDeleteButton)
```

which you could also use as

```
<PartialDeleteButton id={5} />
```

---

i cannot see how these would affect the reconciliation algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I could have another function in between (like you did in your two examples) but that wouldn't qualify as a React component. I know React components are just functions but JSX gives them an extra expressiveness flavour that I was hoping to keep even when partially applying then (if that was even possible). Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @customcommander if you could describe what extra flavour you would like the partial component to have, i could update with relevant parts. The second with the `PartialDeleteButton` is a true react functional component.

Comment: Sure. Well it's pretty much the example in my question: `.map(<Button text="delete" id={__}/>)`. So I suppose the definition of `<Button>` must somehow support a `__` notation that indicates that more props will come, just return another function in the meantime.

Comment: @customcommander not with JSX syntax, since that always end in `React.createElement` which does not return a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no partial render of a component in React.

A component watches on `state` and `props`. Whenever you change either one, it will refresh the component. So if you change `id` dynamically, it will re-render the component.

However that would be 1 extra re-render.

You can however choose to write functions to prevent that like

- `React.memo`: For latest react
- `shouldComponentUpdate`: For older version.

Following is a demo for [React.memo](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/xprz2ye8/2/):

What to look in fiddle, notice I have added a setTimeout that updates `data` and it will call the render of `ToDoApp` but since components are memoised, it will not be called

```js
function Button({id, value}) {
    const onClick = () => {
    console.log(`${id} - ${value}`)
  }
  console.log(`Rendering Btn ${value}`)
    return (<button id={id || '__'} onClick={onClick}>{ value }</button>);
}

const MyButton = React.memo(
    Button,
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return prevProps.value === nextProps.value
  }
)
```

Note: Since you will stop rendering of a component, you will not get updated props in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useCallback` to get a similar effect to partial application:

```
const HelloGreeter = useCallback(({name}: {name: string}) => 
    (<Greeter name={name} greet="hello" />), []);
```

So, in context:

```
interface GreeterProps {
  greet: string
  name: string
}

const Greeter = ({greet, name}: GreeterProps) => (
  <div>{greet}, {name}</div>
);

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [name1, setName1] = useState<string>("world")

  const HelloGreeter = useCallback(({name}: {name: string}) => 
    (<Greeter name={name} greet="hello" />), []);

  const setNameCallback = useCallback((e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    setName1(e.target.value), []);

  return(
    <>
       <HelloGreeter name={name1} >
       <input value={name1} onChange={setNameCallback} />
    </>
  );

}
```

This would not confuse the React renderer, because `useCallback` defines the function once only.